# Twitter oEmbed cross-origin request blocked

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, oembed

I'm trying to use the [Twitter oEmbed API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) to make a request for an embedded tweet. The code is super-simple right now:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=507185938620219395", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I'm getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in Firefox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This will most likely work! `http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Fetching-Cross-Domain-JSON-Tweets-with-JavaScript-and-JSONP`

Comment: @TimothyDalton link is dead.

Comment: @suBDavis try this `https://www.google.com/search?q=Fetching-Cross-Domain-JSON-Tweet‌​s-with-JavaScript-an‌​d-JSONP` , it's the first hit

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "use jsonp"

```
$.ajax({
  type:     "GET",
  url:      "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=507185938620219395",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://ctrlq.org/code/19933-embed-tweet-with-javascript

This one is a workaround for fixing the error

```js
<!--
  Written by Amit Agarwal amit@labnol.org
  Paste this anywhere between the body tag
-->
 
<style>
 
  #tweet {
    width: 400px !important;
  }
 
  #tweet iframe {
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
 
</style>
 
<div id="tweet" tweetID="515490786800963584"></div>
 
<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
 
<script>
 
  window.onload = (function(){
 
    var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
    var id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID");
 
    twttr.widgets.createTweet(
      id, tweet, 
      {
        conversation : 'none',    // or all
        cards        : 'hidden',  // or visible 
        linkColor    : '#cc0000', // default is blue
        theme        : 'light'    // or dark
      })
    .then (function (el) {
      el.contentDocument.querySelector(".footer").style.display = "none";
    });
 
  });
 
</script>
```